# Shortcodes: Return different based on atts

Tags: shortcode

I have the following shortcode for pullquotes:

```
//Pullquote shortcode
function pullQuotes($atts, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "author" => ''
), $atts));
return '<blockquote>'.$content.'<p class="quote-author">' . $author . '</p>    </blockquote>';
}
add_shortcode("pullquote", "pullQuotes");
```

Basically I dont want the paragraph containing the $author attribute to be returned if there is no author set (ie: the default '' value).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is some very simple **IF** logic.

The `$author` variable is set to be empty here `"author" => ''` unless an author name is used in your shortcode.

So now that you know the default value of `$author` you can use **IF** logic to check if it is empty or not. Two logic operators that are useful are `==` (equal to) and `!=` (not equal to). We can use either operator but we only need one.

So first let's check if `$author` is empty.

```
if ( $author == '' ) {

    //do something here

}
```

But now we need to do something if `$author` is not empty. So we can add **else** to our logic.

```
if ( $author == '' ) {

    //do something here if $author is empty

} else {

    //do something here if $author is not empty

}
```

The part of your shortcode function that send the result to the page is this.

```
return '<blockquote>'.$content.'<p class="quote-author">' . $author . '</p>    </blockquote>';
```

So now we can put that inside our **IF** logic.

```
if ( $author == '' ) {

    return '<blockquote>'.$content.'<p class="quote-author">' . $author . '</p>    </blockquote>';

} else {


    return '<blockquote>'.$content.'<p class="quote-author">' . $author . '</p>    </blockquote>';

}
```

But right now the shortcode function *returns* the same results to the page. We need to adjust the first `return` line for when there is no author. That looks like this.

```
if ( $author == '' ) {

    return '<blockquote>'.$content.'</blockquote>';

} else {


    return '<blockquote>'.$content.'<p class="quote-author">' . $author . '</p>    </blockquote>';

}
```

And the final shortcode.

```
//Pullquote shortcode
function pullQuotes($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "author" => ''
    ), $atts));
    if ( $author == '' ) {
        return '<blockquote>'.$content.'</blockquote>';
    } else {
        return '<blockquote>'.$content.'<p class="quote-author">' . $author . '</p>    </blockquote>';
    }
}
add_shortcode("pullquote", "pullQuotes");
```